# Insert dynamic text into Sitecore Rich Text field

Tags: richtextbox, sitecore

I've been spending a bit of time with Sitecore recently, and I noticed the site I am working on has a copyright date in a `Rich Text` field. Unfortunately, it is 2012. Now, the easy way to fix this problem is to simply go in and change the `Rich Text` field which has the copyright information, but I don't want to have to worry about changing it in 2014.

Is there a way to insert dynamic text into the `Text` control? Even if I could have a sigil which I could manually replace in C# that would be preferable to either switching the `Text` for a `Literal` or force manual updates every year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your own processor to the `renderField` pipeline, check whether current field is **RichText** field and replace a token (e.g. __YEAR__) with current year:

```
<renderField>
  <!--... other processors -->
  <processor type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ReplaceTokenProcessor, My.Assembly" />
  <!--... other processors -->
</renderField>
```

and the code of the processor:

```
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
  public class ReplaceTokenProcessor
  {
    public virtual void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
      if (args.FieldTypeKey != "rich text")
        return;

      args.Result.FirstPart = (args.Result.FirstPart == null) ? null : args.Result.FirstPart.Replace("__YEAR__", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
      args.Result.LastPart = (args.Result.LastPart == null) ? null : args.Result.LastPart.Replace("__YEAR__", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need.

Comment: As a note for those unaccustomed to using `processor`s, you should place the `processor` node further down in the `renderField` node to make sure you get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 5):

The solution Maras proposed works, but to me it sounds like a bit overkill for just one date in a RTE field. 
Besides that, every RTE field that is rendered on every single page in your website is processed.

If it is only for one Year-value I would use a Literal and fill and replace the Text property of the Literal in Codebehind:

```
Literal.Text = FieldRenderer.Render(Context.Item, "RTE_FieldName")
                  .Replace("__YEAR__", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
```

Then add caching to the sublayout and it is only rendered once after the cache has been cleared.